# Can nature adapt to life without constant access to sunlight?

Tags: science-based, biology, environment, earth-like

I create a world where the sun's rays no longer reach the planet, due to the clouds completely covering the sky. Nature must therefore adapt to life without constant access to photosynthesis. I haven't found any working examples, but I wonder what would happen to most of the biosphere.

In particular I'm interested in trees, and their possible assimilation with spore plants, those plants that are quite capable of surviving in such an environment, and examples of plants that would have the most impact on humans if they became extinct.